# How to apply class to a specific cell in a Buefy Table?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I would like to know if there is a way in which I can dynamically apply classes targeting a specific cell in a Buefy table. As an example, the following is the code I am working on:

Template:

```
  <b-table :data="status.peerStatus">
    <template slot-scope="props">
      <b-table-column :class="classObject" v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index"
        :label="column.label" :visible="column.visible" :width="200">
        {{ props.row[column.field] }}
      </b-table-column>
    </template>
  </b-table>
```

Script:

```
  computed: {
    classObject() {
      return {
        "has-background-info": true
      };
    }
```

Right now, the whole row is getting highlighted in blue color due the `has-background-info` being set to true.

What I would like to do, however, is to target only a particular cell and apply class conditionally by passing the value of the cell like so.

Right now, what I am trying is passing the value of the cell to `classObject` like this

`<b-table-column :class="classObject(props.row[column.field])" v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index"`

And trying to set the class accordingly

```
 computed: {
    classObject(cellValue) {
      return {
        "has-background-info": cellValue === "YES" ? true : false;
      };
    }
```

However, the above doe not work. Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put it in `method` instead of `computed`

```
methods: {
    classObject(cellValue) {
      return {
        "has-background-info": cellValue === "YES" ? true : false;
      };
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much for the clarification! I know this is a rookie question but why didn't it work when I tried to use `computed` instead of `methods`

Comment: `computed` is a property for **a component**. But in your component, this class value is different for each cell, so it should be calculated dynamically in method.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification once again!