# Vue buefy table cell class based on cell value

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, html-table, buefy

I have a buefy table with values between 0-1000, I want to conditionally highlight the cells in the table based on the cell value. For example is the value is above 50 i want to set the cell background as green, 25-50 to yellow and <25 to red. I saw this previous answer: [How to apply class to a specific cell in a Buefy Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038981/how-to-apply-class-to-a-specific-cell-in-a-buefy-table) But the solution doesnt seem to work.

Here is my current buefy table:

```
    <b-table
      :data="selectedProducts.productQuantities"
      :row-class="(row, index) => row[0] === 'TOTAL'"
    >
      <b-table-column
        label="quantity"
        v-slot="props"
        :class="cellObject(props.quantity)"
        >{{ props.quantity }}
      </b-table-column>
```

And i have a method to calculate and return the class of the cell:

```
  methods: {
    cellObject(quantity){
        if(quantity < 25) {
          return "is-red";
        }
        else if (quantity > 50) {
          return "is-green";
        }
        else {
          return "is-yellow";
      };
    },
```

which returns one of these classes:

```
<style>
.is-red {
  background: #343a40 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.is-yellow {
  background: #ee3f3f !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.is-green {
  background: #41f841 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

After fiddling around with it more i found that if i did :cell-class="is-red" it would apply it to the whole column.

```
     <b-table-column
        label="quantity"
        v-slot="props"
        :cell-class="'is-red'"
        >{{ props.quantity }}
      </b-table-column>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you inspect in dev tools if these classes exists on element ?

Comment: Yes, they do. After fiddling around with it more i found that if i did :cell-class="is-red" it would apply it to the whole column. i added a picture in the question details.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply this to the column, it has to be applied directly to the cell itself. Unfortunately, this is not easily done with a conditional unless you put the conditional in the  tag however, I doubt this will accomplish what you're after. I would recommend that instead, you use a  and just change the background color of the tag based on a conditional. For example, we do something like this:

```
<b-table-column label="Column Label">
  <template v-slot="props">
    <b-tag type="is-primary" v-if="props.row.value > 0 && props.row.value < 25">{{ props.row.value }}</b-tag>
    <b-tag type="is-success" v-else>{{ props.row.value }}</span>
  </template>
</b-table-column>
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but the client wants the whole cell to be coloured. So i'm still stuck trying to find a solution.

Comment: Hm, well, looks like this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038981/how-to-apply-class-to-a-specific-cell-in-a-buefy-table